# Using msvcrt on Android. Or similar

Tags: android, python, msvcrt

so I'm making a small text-based game with python 3.5
and I wanted to add a function something like

"Press Enter to Continue..."

so I searched, and there was this code.

```
def enter():
    input('Press Enter to Continue...")
    import msvcrt as m
    def wait():
         m.getch()
```

I had no idea what msvcrt is(and I still don't...I learned python for a month...) but this worked quite well, until I tried to run my codes on android phone with an app called QPython 3.X.

it turns out that msvcrt is something that is inside windows OS, so I can't use it in android.

so what I am asking is this:
1. is it possible to use(or call) msvcrt in android?
2. can I do "Press Enter to Continue..." in android? I only need the effect like that in anyways.

Thank you guys for reading this.

Comment: Often in python, we can use `os.system('pause')` to achieve press to continue. Also remember to add `import os`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this if you just want to pause:

```
input("Press [Enter] to continue\n")
```